# How to keep this element in this array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array.

```
array(
[PM-AAA] => Array
    (
        [codePm] => PM-32249
        [codeArt] => Array
            (
                [0] => 32249
            )

        [codeArtInFlux] => Array
            (
                [0] => 123456
            )

    )

[PM-BBB] => Array
    (
        [codePm] => PM-32249
        [codeArt] => Array
            (
                [0] => 33270 
            )

        [codeArtInFlux] => Array
            (
                [0] => 484946
            )

    )

[PM-CCC] => Array
    (
        [codePm] => PM-82242
        [codeArt] => Array
            (
                [0] => 82242
                [1] => 82245
                [2] => 82246
            )

        [codeArtInFlux] => Array
            (
                [0] => 5191
                [1] => 51949
                [2] => 26486
            )

    )
)
```

I want keep the array where the "codePm" value is unique. For exemple, in the above array, the "PM-CCC" array will be keep, because the "codePm" is unique, contrary to the "PM-AAA" and "PM-BBB", which share the same "codePm"'s value.

Is it possible to do it with one function ?

Comment: So you want to sort through the arrays and only keep it in the main array if the codePm value is a completely unique value?

Comment: just make mapping [PM-XXX] => [codePM], and a second array whre the codePm is a key.

Comment: do you want that both PM-AAA and PM-BBB is dismissed?

Comment: @iiro > Yes, I want "delete" PM-BBB and CCC

Comment: @bahamut100 please provide example output what do you want .. PM-AAA with PM-BBB or only PM-AAA ...

Comment: @iiro > the output should be only PM-CCC, and not AAA and BBB

Comment: @bahamut100 ok. So you do NOT want to delete PM-BBB and PM-CCC but PM-AAA and PM-BBB.

Comment: @iiro > oh yes, sorry, i'm a moron...

Comment: I think I have the answer, check it please

Comment: @RainHeart257 > yes you have, thanks to iiro too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, there isn't any function that do it directly, you can try this:

```
function insert_unique_key($key_name,$elem,&$array) {
    //Get all elements with the key
    $values=array()
    foreach ($array as $ii) {
        $values[]=$ii[$key_name];
    }

    //Check if the value exists
    if (in_array($elem[$key_name], $values)===FALSE) {
        $array[]=$elem;
    }   
}
```

And in your code:

```
insert_unique_key('codePm',$elem_to_insert,$array_of_elements);
```

And you have to do it for each element of your array into a new array

--

**EDIT**: Sorry, this is for insert new unique values into the array, not for obtain the unique values.

Looking at the comments, I think you want **only** unique values Try this function:

```
function get_uniques_by_subkey($key_name,$array) {
    //Get all elements with the key
    $values=array();
    foreach ($array as $ii) {
        $values[]=$ii[$key_name];
    }

    //Get the elements that only appeared one time
    $count=array_count_values($values);
    unset($values);$values=array();
    foreach ($count as $key => $n) {
        if ($n==1)
            $values[]=$key;
    }

    //Get the values
    $out=array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value[$key_name],$values))
            $out[$key]=$value;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

You can check the result here: http://codepad.org/QmuoYxsk

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
 <?

    function removeDuplicatesByKey($a, $k) {
    $r = array();
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($a as $ind => $arr) {
        $elem_found = array_search($arr[$k], $tmp);

        if ($elem_found === false) {
            $tmp[] = $arr[$k];
            $r[$ind] = $arr;
        } else {
            // ok, element found, need to remove both .. 
            foreach ($r as $index => $r_arr) {
                if ($r_arr[$k] ==  $arr[$k]) {
                    unset($r[$index]);
                }
            }
        }
     }

    return $r;
}
$full_arr = array(
'PM-AAA' => array
    (
        'codePm' => 'PM-32249',
        'codeArt' => array(
                '0' => 32249
            ),
        'codeArtInFlux' => array(
                '0' => 123456
            )
 )
,
'PM-BBB' => array
    (
        'codePm' => 'PM-32249',
        'codeArt' => array
            (
                '0' => 33270 
            ),

        'codeArtInFlux' => array
            (
                '0' => 484946
            )

    )
,
'PM-CCC' => array
    (
        'codePm' => 'PM-82242',
        'codeArt' => array
            (
                '0' => 82242,
                '1' => 82245,
                '2' => 82246
            ),

        'codeArtInFlux' => array
            (
                '0' => 5191,
                '1' => 51949,
                '2' => 26486
            )

    )
);


print_r(removeDuplicatesByKey($full_arr, 'codePm'));

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [codePm] => PM-82242
            [codeArt] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 82242
                    [1] => 82245
                    [2] => 82246
                )

            [codeArtInFlux] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5191
                    [1] => 51949
                    [2] => 26486
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thank, but the result must be PM-CCC only

Answer (score 0):

I made this....on speed mode in my work....you can improve it ;)

```
    $array = array( 

        'PM-AAA' => array(
        'codePm' => 'PM-32249',
        'codeArt' => array(32249),
        'codeArtInFlux' => array(123456)

    ),

        'PM-BBB' => array(
        'codePm' => 'PM-32249',
        'codeArt' => array(33270 ),
        'codeArtInFlux' => array(484946)
         ),

        'PM-CCC' => array(
        'codePm' => 'PM-82242',
        'codeArt' => array(82242,82245,82246),
        'codeArtInFlux' => array(5191,51949,26486)

    )
);



$code_count = array(); 
$arr2 = array();
foreach($array as $counter) {  

        $key = $counter['codePm']; 
        $code_count[] = $key;

}
$arr2 = (array_count_values($code_count));
print_r($arr2); //now i know how many times my code is repeated

while ($code_name = current($arr2)) {
    if ($code_name == 1) {
        $unique_code = key($arr2);
    }
    next($arr2);
}

echo $unique_code."</br>"; //i have my unique code

foreach ($array as $key) {
  var_dump($key);
  if($key['codePm']==$unique_code)
  $arr_aux = $key;  
}

echo "I have mi array ready with the unique val ;) </br>";

var_dump($arr_aux);
```

Saludos ;)